# Outlook for Mac: Filter Unread never matches the Inbox badge count

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, office-for-mac

I've looked through the various answers about counts being wrong, but none of them seem to address this issue directly.

I have a current version Outlook for Mac (v16.39 - Office 365)

When I read through my new mail each day, I always wind up with the inbox badge still showing a positive value for unread mail while my Filter Inbox "Unread" shows "no results" (see screenshot).

Is there some categorization of emails that make the badge count valid while not showing as unread for the filter?  Is there a way to bring these in line so they both use the same criteria?  Thanks

[image]

Comment: Odd, I've got the 2016 version of Outlook and that works fine for me. At the bottom of the Filter menu is a "Clear all filters" item. Maybe you have an active filter you don't know about? Try that option.

Comment: I should have mentioned it above, but yes I’ve toggle back and forth between clear all filters and Unread repeatedly to no avail.

Comment: Have the same issue. Haven't find solution yet.

Comment: Same here. Mind blowing this doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue was occurring for me. Here's how I resolved it:

1. Login to https://outlook.office.com/mail/inbox
2. Right Click Inbox
3. Select mark All as read

This sets the unreads to 0 and should update on your Outlook client shortly after.

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround more than an actual solution. In my case I wanted to see what the unread messages were, before either deleting them/marking them as read. The solution is to simply sort your folder by "Status" in descending order and collapse the "Calendar" category to see the Unread category.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem that has only recently occurred? Can this function work normally before?
I did the same tests in my Outlook(Version 16.39 20071300) and found that the Filter feature could work fine. As I know, when multiple filter conditions are set, issues like this might happen. In order to further confirm your issue, it is suggested to Clear All Filters first and then choose unread filter to see if it can normally show the correct results. You could also do tests to check if other filter conditions can get the correct results.

If the issue still continues, I'm afraid that there might be something wrong with your Outlook client. Please try to [completely uninstall your Outlook and reinstall it][1] to solve your issue.

[1]: https://support.office.com/client/Troubleshoot-Office-2016-for-Mac-issues-by-completely-uninstalling-before-you-reinstall-ec3aa66e-6a76-451f-9d35-cba2e14e94c0)

Comment: Thanks, Jeff.  However, as this pretty much amounts to a guess and not an answer, it probably should have been posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue with Outlook on my Mac. I was finally able to locate the "unread" emails by opening Outlook on my mobile device (iPhone), filtering for unread, and there were the mysterious unread emails that weren't appearing in my desktop Outlook application.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (Outlook for Mac - Nov '22) and is a more reliable way to track unread emails.

1. Flag each unread email. Unfortunately, you may have to scroll through your emails.
2. Sort by flagged emails so they all appear at the top of the viewing pane.
3. Select all the flagged/unread emails and mark them as read.
4. Select all the emails you want to mark as unread (these should be flagged and the ones you previously selected) and set them as unread.
5. You can sort the emails however you like at this point. I normally sort by date received (newest on top).
6. If you filter by unread emails, you should see all your unread emails - Your Welcome =)

For me anyway, I think Outlook must have got the unread "flags/switch/indicator/{whatever you want to call it}" confused. By marking all emails as read, then unread seems to unconfuse - technical term =) Outlook.

Also, I have concluded it is better to also flag my unread emails to ensure I will also be able to located them as sometimes, when you work too quickly and you toggle the unread emails filter, the last email you selected will become read, and if you select unread filter again, the email will no longer be unread and you'll have to rely on your memory to locate the email(s). Not an issue if you have a small handful of emails, but a headache if you have hundreds or thousands of emails.

Anyway... have a good day. =)